# Как скомпилировть/собрать библиотеку XLNT?

Tags: c++, excel

Скачал библиотеку xlnt для работы с екселем - https://github.com/tfussell/xlnt. Подскажите пожалуйста, что мне с ней дальше делать ? Честно, я так и не могу понять, как из всего того кол-во файлов, которые есть в скаченном архиве, а там их штук 100 .hpp и .cpp - файлов, что с ними делать ?

1)Насколько я понимаю их как то надо обработать программой Cmake и вроде бы наверное на выходе должен появится .lib файл,но абсолютно не могу понять, как это сделать и точно ли  на выходе должно после такой обработки получится .lib файл.
2)Или как то напрямую из можно Visual Studio 2017 обработать ?

Помогите пожалуйста.

Comment: там же на странице приведён пример

Comment: Он вроде, как для Ubuntu ?

Comment: ЕМНИП, cmake, кроме прочего, можно заставить сгенерировать проект для visual studio, компиляция которого даст .lib. *"абсолютно не могу понять, как это сделать"* Ну, вы cmake скачали? Запускать пробовали? Там же интерфейс относительно простой, нужно выбрать папку с кодом библиотеки и нажать пару кнопок.

Comment: В смысле для Ubuntu? Там include файлов исходных

Comment: Конечно же Cmake скачал. Запускал, указывал папку Source, Cmake создавал кучу файлов, но среди них не было не одного файла .lib, поэтому и не понимаю.

Comment: да, блин, вам же уже написали, что cmake делает проект для VS, https://tfussell.gitbooks.io/xlnt/content/docs/introduction/Installation.html

Comment: Проверьте build directory еще раз, поищите проект. Не найдете - опишите подробно, что делали, какие кнопки нажимали и т. п.

Comment: 1)Я не могу понять, что значит проект для VS ? Я хочу подключить к своему проекту скачанную xlnt библиотеку, как я понял, для этого нужно эту скачанную библиотеку, с помощью Cmake преобразовать в .lib файл, для того чтобы уже в своем проекте в Visual Studio указать путь к этому .lib файлу и указать include на заголовочный файл .h.Правильно ?

Comment: 2)Файла с расширением .lib нет 100%. Я запускаю Cmake - в строке "Where is the source" указываю путь: C:/11/xlnt-master/xlnt-master/source, потом указываю путь для "Where build the binaries" и нажимаю generate, Cmake создает много файлов, но .lib файла среди них нет.

Comment: Вам же сказали, Сmake создает проект для вашей ide. Для какой выбирается в Cmake. Потом этот проект надо в вашей ide запустить и скомпилировать и тогда, создастся файл библиотеки. cmake только настраивает проект для сборки. Но для сборки нужен компилятор. который есть в вашей ide. Или чем вы там пользуетесь.

Comment: Nik, Спасибо!  Под созданным Cmake проектом имеется ввиду файлы .sln (просто Cmake создал много файлов) ? Если да, то какой их двух файлов созданных Cmake`ом нужно открыть в IDE - libstudxml.sln или xlnt.sln ? Подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Скомпилируйте оба, не ошибетесь. :)

Comment: Еще, когда отвечаете людям, начинайте комментарии с `@username`. Иначе мы не получаем уведомления, и скорее всего не ответим. Вы уведомления получаете всегда, потому что комментарии - под вашим постом.

Comment: HolyBlackCat, загрузил  в VS, "собрал" этот проект, VS создал много файлов, среди который был .lib файл, по идее файл статической библиотеки, которую потом можно будет подключить к своему проекту.                                                                                                        Создал новый проект в VS,  там указал путь к .lib файлу, указал #include .h, нажал компилироваться, но VS выдал ошибку - "Запуск программы невозможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует xlntd.dll..".  Но причем тут dll, ведь я указывал путь для .lib файла, и не хочу чтобы библиотека подключалась дин.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat, загрузил в VS, "собрал" этот проект, VS создал много файлов, среди который был .lib файл, по идее файл статической библиотеки, которую потом можно будет подключить к своему проекту. Создал новый проект в VS, там указал путь к .lib файлу, указал #include .h, нажал компилироваться, но VS выдал ошибку - "Запуск программы невозможен, так как на компьютере отсутствует xlntd.dll..". Но причем тут dll, ведь я указывал путь для .lib файла, и не хочу чтобы библиотека подключалась динамически.

Comment: С VS не знаком, так что подсказать не смогу...