# Подключение и настройка внешней библиотеки в VS(xlnt - библиотека)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, excel, библиотеки

Есть небольшая проблема, недавно прочитал [Как скомпилировть/собрать библиотеку XLNT?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/929725/323031)
Никогда не подключал библиотек к VS. Решил попробовать на этом примере. После компиляции, в папке Debug получил список файлов с именем xlntd, с расширениями .dll, .exp, .ilk, .lib, .pdb. Что делать дальше - не знаю. Пробовал искать, менять какие-то настройки - не получилось ничего. Какой алгоритм действий дальше? Подскажите возможно какие - либо информационные ресурсы где можно подробно об этом прочитать(моя ide Visual Studio Enterprise 2017).